# eclipse .project workspace location - maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I have set up in my maven pom file linkedResources that are pointing to other project in my workspace.

I am now trying to setup pom file so its platform independent (unix / windows ).

```
<linkedResource>
    <name>src/main/webapp/realtime</name>
    <type>2</type>
    <location>${maven.workspace}/OrderlyTelecomsMVN/orderlyq/src/main/webapp/realtime</location>
</linkedResource>
```

and when i run mvn eclipse:eclipse to generate .project file this ${maven.workspace} is not resolved properly resulting in not copying required resources from one project to another.

I have also tried:

```
<location>${ECLIPSE_HOME}/workspace/OrderlyTelecomsMVN/orderlyq/src/main/webapp/realtime</location>
```

but still not luck. It only seems to be working when i hardcode the path but that is not desirable as we are running different machines (unix / windows) and workspace can be anywhere on the system.

does any one know of a solution what variable i can use so it resolves to ....../workspace directory.

PS. Also i have the same problem with maven-antrun-plugin. In order for it to work i have to hardcode paths. When someone pull repo from repository it overrides users config.

Thanks

Comment: With the precondition that all projects reside in the workspace directory, you could have `<location>${project.basedir}/../OrderlyTelecomsMVN/orderlyq/src/main/webapp/realtime</location>`. Does that work?

Comment: ${project.basedir} does not resolve to workspace. it will resolve to orderlyq

Comment: That's why I added a `/..` to it. It steps up one direcory in the path.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose still did not work, however it seems like i have found solution <locationURI>WORKSPACE_LOC/......</locationURI> <- this seems to be resolving workspace location just fine

Comment: Remove this configuration file cause if you open other projects in your current workspace and if they have dependencies Eclipse will automatically resolve against Eclipse workspace.